# How to set left padding for only EditText without changing hint padding inside TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

When I set paddingStart for my EditText inside TextInputLayout, the floating hint is also moved left. How to set padding for my edittext keeping TextInputLayout hint staying at left as default?

Below is my code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/cardNumberTil"
    style="@style/AuthTheme.NumberEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/CaptionLink">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Some hint here"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingStart="45dp"
            android:text="12345678"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Body1Style"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />    
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


Here are styles:

<style name="Body1Style">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/sans_serif_regular</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">8sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="CaptionLink">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">8sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#0089d0</item>
</style>

<style name="AuthTheme.NumberEditText" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/textColorSubtitle1Gray</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/cerulean</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/cerulean</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/cerulean</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">8sp</item>
</style>
```

[desired output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXjM5.png)

Comment: Could you upload desired & current output pictures

Comment: can you please post your style : @style/CaptionLink and @style/Body1Style

Comment: I added desired picture @Jasurbek

Comment: Added @MiteshMachhoya